# Limit of $i^{n!}-2^{-n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I ran into this problem in Palka's Book which said to compute the limit of $z_n=i^{n!}+2^{-n}$. My approach was to consider the real and imaginary limits separately. Clearly the limit of the real part of the complex sequence is $0$. However,
$$\mathrm{Im}(z_n)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi n!}{2}\right)$$ 
I don't think this converges. Appreciate any help. Thanks

Edit: On the other hand I just realized $i^{n!}$ is not always imaginary. Anyway hope someone could answer this

Comment: What is n approaching?

Comment: @Brad Clearly infinity

Comment: Why is there a minus sign in the title but a plus sign in the body?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Sorry about that but it does not affect the answer anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** for $n \geq 4$ we know that $n!$ is a multiple of $4$. Therefore, for $n \geq 4$ we have $i^{n!}=1$.

So your sequence becomes 
$$z_n=2^{-n}+1 \, \forall n \geq 4$$
Now, it is easy to consider this sequence, and the first three terms make absolutely no difference for the limit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this a better approach than what I said I tried in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Heisenberg The approach you tried also works but with a small modification, and this is what Brad pointed. You split your sequence in two parts and prove that each is convergent, then their sum must be convergent...So instead of splitting into real and imaginary, you just split that way as the sum of two sequences...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to say that $2^{-n}$ goes to 0. So instead we will focus on the imaginary part. We know that n is approaching infinity and we also know that 4 time any integer is still divisible by 4. Thus we can say n! is divisible by 4 and thus $i^{n!}$ approaches 1. So $z_n$ approaches 1.

Comment: Check out my edit. $i^{n!}$ is not always imaginary so we cannot really distinguish which and which is real and imaginary right?

Comment: @Heisenberg To fix this issue, define $x_n=i^{n!}$ and $y_n=2^{-n}$. Don't think about them as real/imaginary parts, think just sequences. Now if $x_n, y_n$ are convergent, so is $x_n+y_n$....